# difference between scanf("%c" , ..) and getchar()

Tags: c, io

I always think `scanf("%c" , &addr);` is equal to `getchar()` before I test this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%c",&i);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i == EOF)
        printf("EOF int type and char input\n");
    i =getchar();
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i == EOF)
        printf("EOF int type and char input\n");
}
```

I got output when I use "Ctrl+D" twice:

> -1217114112
>
> -1
>
> EOF int type and char input

Since EOF is `-1` in `int` type ,I also try use `scanf("%d",&i);` replace `scanf("%c",&i)` , just get the same output.

I got confused.  Can anybody explain this for me?

----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------

I want to know the behavior of `scanf("%c",i)` of Ctrl+D , I do test:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    j = scanf("%c",&i);
    printf("%c\n", i);
    printf("%d\n", j);
    if(i == EOF)
        printf("EOF int type and char input");
     i =getchar();
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i == EOF)
        printf("EOF int type and char input");
}
```

OutPut:

```
k                  // If the scanf set 1 byte in i , why here print 'k' ?
-1
-1
EOF int type and char input
```

Comment: The `k` in the output is the random garbage value that was in `i` before you tried to abuse it by passing it to `scanf()` to be processed as a `char` instead of the `int` that it is.  When `scanf()` encounters EOF (zero characters to read), it doesn't assign to the variable at all; it merely returns EOF.  If `j` is not 1, there is nothing useful you can say about what is in `i`; its value is indeterminate (but probably the same as you started with before the function call — but in the sample code, that is undefined because `i` is not initialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison does not fully set `i` as it involves Undefined Behavior (UB).

```
int i;            // the value of i could be anything
scanf("%c",&i);   // At most, only 1 byte of i is set, the remaining bytes are still unknown.
printf("%d\n", i);// Your are printing 'i' whose value is not fully determined.
```

Had you tried

```
char ch;
int y = scanf("%c",&ch);
printf("%d\n", ch);
if(ch == EOF)
```

You would potentially make a match even though the input was not EOF.  Had you scanned in a `char` with the value of 255, the char would take on the 2s compliment 8-bit value of -1.  The comparison would sign extend the 8-bit -1 to match the `int` size and you would match -1.
(Assumptions: 2s compliment integers, 8-bit byte, EOF  == -1, char is signed).

**The correct EOF test is**

```
int y = scanf("%c",&ch);
if (y == EOF)
```

Note: `getchar()` & `scanf()` return `EOF` implies End-of-file **or** I/O error.  A subsequent check of `ferror(stdin)` distinguishes this.

Comment: I do test and it shows `scanf` return `-1` , so is the 1 byte set by scanf or not?

Comment: No, 1 byte is not set.  Only if `scanf("%c",&i)` returned 1 would the one byte in `i` get set.  Of course, the other bytes of `i` are not changed.

Answer (score 3):

The first value is probably undefined behavior. You can't rely on `i` having a value unless `scanf()` returns 1.

With `scanf()` in particular, you seem to be confusing the scanned value (the conversion of characters according to a format specifier in the first argument) with the return value of the function call.

With `getchar()`, of course, this distinction doesn't exist since it *only* has a return value.

Comment: E .. Yes ,`scanf` return -1!

Comment: I edit my question, when scanf return `-1` , what exactly happened in address of `i` ?